# Height equal css classes based on content

Tags: html, css

I want to have all `news`and `comments` elements to have the same height based on the largest element. So both columns will also have the same height. 
The best would be an only CSS solution.
The HTML structure can´t be changed, the elements can also have different parents. 
The data in the elements changes via ajax every 5 minutes, so after reloading the data, the height needs to get changed.

I already got a JS solution but it´s inefficient. If there isn´t a CSS solution I will stick with that. I tried around with flexbox.

```css
.column2, .column1 {
  border: solid;
  width: 48%;
  position:relative;
  float: left;
}
.news, .comments {
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="column1">
  <div class="news" id="news2">
    Some text
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="comments" id="comments2">
   A list of comments 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="column2">
  <div class="news" id="news2">
    Some other text
  </div>
  <div class="comments" id="comments2">
    A list of different comments
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with the question which I could improve? Or why the downvotes ?

Comment: Are you just wanting columns to match heights or do you need the news to match the news height in the next column?  If the former, do your columns have a wrapper div?  If the latter, not possible without js with your html structure

Comment: @Pete yes I want the news match the news height, already thought it's not possible

Answer (score 0):

If you put a *wrapper* around their *parents*, `display` it as `flex`, as well as the *parents* themselves, and make the `.news` **or** `.comments` *section* of *flexible height* with `flex: 1`, which will match them in *height*, you would still need to define the *fixed* `height` for the other, optimally together with the `overflow-y: auto`, to achieve the desired result. This is about as further you can get pure *CSS / Flexbox* way:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.column1, .column2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.news {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.comments {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="column1">
    <div class="news" id="news1">
      Some text
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="comments" id="comments1">
     A list of comments
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column2">
    <div class="news" id="news2">
      Some other text
    </div>
    <div class="comments" id="comments2">
      A list of different comments
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Since it's all so flexible, I would rotate it all 90 degrees and approach it via rows instead of columns.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: thin solid gray;
}

.news,
.comments {
  border: thin solid purple;
  width: 48%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="news" id="news1">
    Some other text
  </div>
  <div class="news" id="news2">
    Some text
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="comments" id="comments1">
    A list of comments
  </div>
  <div class="comments" id="comments2">
    A list of different comments
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a cool solution but it changes the html structure and moves the elements to different parents